# ydata_profiling throwing error in Library Update

Tags: python, pandas, pydantic

I wish to use the ydata_profiling library. I am able to use it when I am running the older version of Pydantic and Pydantic-settings.

Code:

```
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
```

But when I update these libraries, the following error gets thrown:

> PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings for more details.
>
> For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/u/import-error

[image]

Used both versions of the libraries. Cannot use pandas_profiling since it has I believe been deprecated.